# Declaration error at define_state.h: identifier is already declared in the present scope

Tags: verilog, quartus

All I am trying to do right now is get past this error, so I can start testing the code. It is for a hardware image decompressor.

The main .v file:

```
`timescale 1ns/100ps

`ifndef DISABLE_DEFAULT_NET
`default_nettype none
`endif

`include "define_state.h"

// This is the top module
// It connects the UART, SRAM and VGA together.
// It gives access to the SRAM for UART and VGA
module experiment4a (
  /////// board clocks                      ////////////
  input logic CLOCK_50_I,                   // 50 MHz clock

  /////// pushbuttons/switches              ////////////
  input logic[3:0] PUSH_BUTTON_I,           // pushbuttons
  input logic[17:0] SWITCH_I,               // toggle switches

  /////// 7 segment displays/LEDs           ////////////
  output logic[6:0] SEVEN_SEGMENT_N_O[7:0], // 8 seven segment displays
  output logic[8:0] LED_GREEN_O,            // 9 green LEDs

  /////// VGA interface                     ////////////
  output logic VGA_CLOCK_O,                 // VGA clock
  output logic VGA_HSYNC_O,                 // VGA H_SYNC
  output logic VGA_VSYNC_O,                 // VGA V_SYNC
  output logic VGA_BLANK_O,                 // VGA BLANK
  output logic VGA_SYNC_O,                  // VGA SYNC
  output logic[7:0] VGA_RED_O,              // VGA red
  output logic[7:0] VGA_GREEN_O,            // VGA green
  output logic[7:0] VGA_BLUE_O,             // VGA blue

  /////// SRAM Interface                    ////////////
  inout wire[15:0] SRAM_DATA_IO,            // SRAM data bus 16 bits
  output logic[19:0] SRAM_ADDRESS_O,        // SRAM address bus 18 bits
  output logic SRAM_UB_N_O,                 // SRAM high-byte data mask
  output logic SRAM_LB_N_O,                 // SRAM low-byte data mask
  output logic SRAM_WE_N_O,                 // SRAM write enable
  output logic SRAM_CE_N_O,                 // SRAM chip enable
  output logic SRAM_OE_N_O,                 // SRAM output logic enable

  /////// UART                              ////////////
  input logic UART_RX_I,                    // UART receive signal
  output logic UART_TX_O                    // UART transmit signal
);

  logic resetn;

  top_state_type top_state;
  state_type state;

  // For Push button
  logic [3:0] PB_pushed;

  // For VGA SRAM interface
  logic VGA_enable;
  logic [17:0] VGA_base_address;
  logic [17:0] VGA_SRAM_address;

  // For SRAM
  logic [17:0] SRAM_address;
  logic [15:0] SRAM_write_data;
  logic SRAM_we_n;
  logic [15:0] SRAM_read_data;
  logic SRAM_ready;

  //For Milestone 1
  parameter Y_offset = 0;
  parameter U_offset = 38400;
  parameter V_offset = 57600;
  parameter RGB_offset = 146944;
  logic [17:0] y_loc, uv_loc, rgb_loc;
  logic [15:0] red, green, blue, r_hold, g_hold, b_hold;
  logic [15:0] y, y_hold, u_prime, u_hold, v_prime, v_hold;
  logic [7:0] u_comp [5:0];
  logic [7:0] v_comp [5:0];
  logic u_v_toggle;
  logic lead_in;
  logic [7:0] mult_1, mult_2, mult_3;


  // For UART SRAM interface
  logic UART_rx_enable;
  logic UART_rx_initialize;
  logic [17:0] UART_SRAM_address;
  logic [15:0] UART_SRAM_write_data;
  logic UART_SRAM_we_n;
  logic [25:0] UART_timer;

  logic [6:0] value_7_segment [7:0];

  // For error detection in UART
  logic [3:0] Frame_error;

  // For disabling UART transmit
  assign UART_TX_O = 1'b1;

  assign resetn = ~SWITCH_I[17] && SRAM_ready;

  // Push Button unit
  PB_Controller PB_unit (
    .Clock_50(CLOCK_50_I),
    .Resetn(resetn),
    .PB_signal(PUSH_BUTTON_I),
    .PB_pushed(PB_pushed)
  );

  // VGA SRAM interface
  logic [9:0] VGA_RED_O_long, VGA_GREEN_O_long, VGA_BLUE_O_long;

  VGA_SRAM_interface VGA_unit (
    .Clock(CLOCK_50_I),
    .Resetn(resetn),
    .VGA_enable(VGA_enable),

    // For accessing SRAM
    .SRAM_base_address(VGA_base_address),
    .SRAM_address(VGA_SRAM_address),
    .SRAM_read_data(SRAM_read_data),

    // To VGA pins
    .VGA_CLOCK_O(VGA_CLOCK_O),
    .VGA_HSYNC_O(VGA_HSYNC_O),
    .VGA_VSYNC_O(VGA_VSYNC_O),
    .VGA_BLANK_O(VGA_BLANK_O),
    .VGA_SYNC_O(VGA_SYNC_O),
    .VGA_RED_O(VGA_RED_O_long),
    .VGA_GREEN_O(VGA_GREEN_O_long),
    .VGA_BLUE_O(VGA_BLUE_O_long)
  );

  assign VGA_RED_O = VGA_RED_O_long[9:2];
  assign VGA_GREEN_O = VGA_GREEN_O_long[9:2];
  assign VGA_BLUE_O = VGA_BLUE_O_long[9:2];

  // UART SRAM interface
  UART_SRAM_interface UART_unit(
    .Clock(CLOCK_50_I),
    .Resetn(resetn),

    .UART_RX_I(UART_RX_I),
    .Initialize(UART_rx_initialize),
    .Enable(UART_rx_enable),

    // For accessing SRAM
    .SRAM_address(UART_SRAM_address),
    .SRAM_write_data(UART_SRAM_write_data),
    .SRAM_we_n(UART_SRAM_we_n),
    .Frame_error(Frame_error)
  );

  // SRAM unit
  SRAM_Controller SRAM_unit (
    .Clock_50(CLOCK_50_I),
    .Resetn(~SWITCH_I[17]),
    .SRAM_address(SRAM_address),
    .SRAM_write_data(SRAM_write_data),
    .SRAM_we_n(SRAM_we_n),
    .SRAM_read_data(SRAM_read_data),
    .SRAM_ready(SRAM_ready),

    // To the SRAM pins
    .SRAM_DATA_IO(SRAM_DATA_IO),
    .SRAM_ADDRESS_O(SRAM_ADDRESS_O[17:0]),
    .SRAM_UB_N_O(SRAM_UB_N_O),
    .SRAM_LB_N_O(SRAM_LB_N_O),
    .SRAM_WE_N_O(SRAM_WE_N_O),
    .SRAM_CE_N_O(SRAM_CE_N_O),
    .SRAM_OE_N_O(SRAM_OE_N_O)
  );

  assign SRAM_ADDRESS_O[19:18] = 2'b00;

  always @(posedge CLOCK_50_I or negedge resetn) begin
    if (~resetn) begin
      top_state <= S_IDLE;

      UART_rx_initialize <= 1'b0;
      UART_rx_enable <= 1'b0;
      UART_timer <= 26'd0;

      VGA_enable <= 1'b1;
    end else begin
      UART_rx_initialize <= 1'b0;
      UART_rx_enable <= 1'b0;

      // Timer for timeout on UART
      // This counter reset itself every time a new data is received on UART
      if (UART_rx_initialize | ~UART_SRAM_we_n) UART_timer <= 26'd0;
      else UART_timer <= UART_timer + 26'd1;

      case (top_state)
        S_IDLE: begin
          VGA_enable <= 1'b1;
          if (~UART_RX_I | PB_pushed[0]) begin
            // UART detected a signal, or PB0 is pressed
            UART_rx_initialize <= 1'b1;

            VGA_enable <= 1'b0;

            top_state <= S_ENABLE_UART_RX;
          end
        end
        S_ENABLE_UART_RX: begin
          // Enable the UART receiver
          UART_rx_enable <= 1'b1;
          top_state <= S_WAIT_UART_RX;
        end
        S_WAIT_UART_RX: begin
          if ((UART_timer == 26'd49999999) && (UART_SRAM_address != 18'h00000)) begin
            // Timeout for 1 sec on UART for detecting if file transmission is finished
            UART_rx_initialize <= 1'b1;

            VGA_enable <= 1'b1;
            top_state <= S_IDLE;
          end
        end
        default: top_state <= S_IDLE;
      endcase
    end
  end

  assign VGA_base_address = 18'd0;

  // Give access to SRAM for UART and VGA at appropriate time
  assign SRAM_address = ((top_state == S_ENABLE_UART_RX) | (top_state == S_WAIT_UART_RX))
    ? UART_SRAM_address
    : VGA_SRAM_address;

  assign SRAM_write_data = UART_SRAM_write_data;

  assign SRAM_we_n = ((top_state == S_ENABLE_UART_RX) | (top_state == S_WAIT_UART_RX))
    ? UART_SRAM_we_n
    : 1'b1;

  //Milestone 1
  always_ff @ (posedge CLOCK_50_I or negedge resetn) begin
    if (resetn == 1'b0) begin
      SRAM_we_n <= 1'b1;
      SRAM_write_data <= 16'd0;
      SRAM_address <= 18'd0;

      red = 16'd0;
      green = 16'd0;
      blue = 16'd0;
      r_hold = 16'd0;
      g_hold = 16'd0;
      b_hold = 16'd0;

      y = 16'd0;
      y_hold = 16'd0;

      u_prime = 16'd0;
      u_hold = 16'd0;
      u_comp [0] = 8'd0;
      u_comp [1] = 8'd0;
      u_comp [2] = 8'd0;
      u_comp [3] = 8'd0;
      u_comp [4] = 8'd0;
      u_comp [5] = 8'd0;

      v_prime  = 16'd0;
      v_hold = 16'd0;
      v_comp [0] = 8'd0;
      v_comp [1] = 8'd0;
      v_comp [2] = 8'd0;
      v_comp [3] = 8'd0;
      v_comp [4] = 8'd0;
      v_comp [5] = 8'd0;

      u_v_toggle = 8'd0;

      lead_in = 1'b1;

      state <= S_IDLE;
    end else begin
      case (state)
        S_IDLE: begin
          red = 16'd0;
          green = 16'd0;
          blue = 16'd0;
          r_hold = 16'd0;
          g_hold = 16'd0;
          b_hold = 16'd0;

          y = 16'd0;
          y_hold = 16'd0;

          u_prime = 16'd0;
          u_hold = 16'd0;
          u_comp [0] = 8'd0;
          u_comp [1] = 8'd0;
          u_comp [2] = 8'd0;
          u_comp [3] = 8'd0;
          u_comp [4] = 8'd0;
          u_comp [5] = 8'd0;

          v_prime  = 16'd0;
          v_hold = 16'd0;
          v_comp [0] = 8'd0;
          v_comp [1] = 8'd0;
          v_comp [2] = 8'd0;
          v_comp [3] = 8'd0;
          v_comp [4] = 8'd0;
          v_comp [5] = 8'd0;

          u_v_toggle = 8'd0;


          SRAM_address <= U_offset;
          uv_loc <= 18'd0;
          y_loc <= 18'd0;
          rgb_loc <= 18'd0;
          SRAM_we_n <= 1'b0;
          lead_in <=1'b1;

          state <= S_LEAD_IN_1_U;
        end

        S_LEAD_IN_1_U: begin
          u_hold <= SRAM_read_data;
             u_comp [5] <=u_hold[15:8];
             u_comp [4] <=u_hold[15:8];
          u_comp [3] <=u_hold[15:8];
          u_comp [2] <=u_hold[7:0];
          SRAM_address <= SRAM_address + 18'd1;
          uv_loc <= uv_loc + 18'd1;
          state<= S_LEAD_IN_2_U;
        end

        S_LEAD_IN_2_U: begin
          u_hold <= SRAM_read_data;
          u_comp [1] <=u_hold[15:8];
          u_comp [0] <=u_hold[7:0];
          SRAM_address <= V_offset;
          state<= S_LEAD_IN_3_V;
        end

        S_LEAD_IN_3_V: begin
          v_hold <= SRAM_read_data;
             v_comp [5] <=u_hold[15:8];
             v_comp [4] <=u_hold[15:8];
          v_comp [3] <=u_hold[15:8];
          v_comp [2] <=u_hold[7:0];
          SRAM_address <= SRAM_address + 18'd1;
          state<= S_LEAD_IN_4_V;
        end

        S_LEAD_IN_4_V: begin
          v_hold <= SRAM_read_data;
          v_comp [1] <=u_hold[15:8];
          v_comp [0] <=u_hold[7:0];
          SRAM_address <= Y_offset;
          state<= S_LEAD_IN_Y;
        end

        S_LEAD_IN_Y: begin
          y = SRAM_read_data;
          u_prime [15:8] <= u_comp[3];
          mult_1 <= 159*(u_comp[3]+u_comp[2]);
          mult_2 <= 52*(u_comp[4]+u_comp[1]);
          mult_3 <= 21*(u_comp[5]+u_comp[0]);
          u_prime [7:0] <= mult_1 - mult_2 + mult_3;
          y_loc < y_loc + 18'd1
          SRAM_address <= SRAM_address + 18'd1;
          state <= S_READ_Y;
        end

        S_READ_Y: begin
          y_hold <= SRAM_read_data;
          r = r_hold;
          g = g_hold;
          b = b_hold;
          v_prime [15:8] <= v_comp[3];
          mult_1 <= 159*(v_comp[3]+v_comp[2]);
          mult_2 <= 52*(v_comp[4]+v_comp[1]);
          mult_3 <= 21*(v_comp[5]+v_comp[0]);
          v_prime [7:0] <= mult_1 - mult_2 + mult_3;
          uv_loc <= uv_loc + 18'd1;
          SRAM_address <= U_offset + uv_loc;
          state <= S_READ_U;
        end

        S_READ_U: begin
          //still need the read u and if statement for every other clock cycle
          if(u_v_toggle == 8'd0) begin // toggle == 0, then read
                         u_hold <= SRAM_read_data;
          end
          mult_1 <= 76284*(y[15:8]-16);
          mult_2 <= 104595*(v_prime[15:8]-128);
          mult_3 <= 132251*(u_prime[15:8]-128);
          r_hold [15:8] = mult_1 + mult_2;
          b_hold [15:8] = mult_1 + mult_3;
          SRAM_address <= V_offset + uv_loc;
          state <= S_READ_V;
        end

        S_READ_V: begin
        if(u_v_toggle == 8'd0) begin // toggle == 0, then read
             v_hold <= SRAM_read_data;
        end
          mult_2 <= 53281(v_prime[15:8] - 128);
          mult_3 <= 25624(u_prime[15:8] - 128);
          g_hold [15:8] <= mult_1 - mult_2 - mult_3;
          SRAM_address <= RGB_offset + rgb_loc;
          state <= S_WRITE_R;
        end

        S_WRITE_R: begin
          mult_1 <= 76284*(y[7:0]-16);
          mult_2 <= 104595*(v_prime[7:0]-128);
          mult_3 <= 132251*(u_prime[7:0]-128);
          r_hold [7:0] = mult_1 + mult_2;
          b_hold [7:0] = mult_1 + mult_3;

          u_comp[5] = u_comp[4];
          u_comp[4] = u_comp[3];
          u_comp[3] = u_comp[2];
          u_comp[2] = u_comp[1];
          u_comp[1] = u_hold[7:0];

             if(lead_in == 1'b0) begin
                    //if its not lead in then do the write to R othewise skip it
                    SRAM_write_data <= r;

                    rgb_loc <= rgb_loc + 18'd1;
                    SRAM_address <= SRAM_address + rgb_loc;
                end
          state <= S_WRITE_G;
        end

        S_WRITE_G: begin
          mult_2 <= 53281(v_prime[7:0] - 128);
          mult_3 <= 25624(u_prime[7:0] - 128);
          g_hold [7:0] <= mult_1 - mult_2 - mult_3;

           if(lead_in == 1'b0) begin
               SRAM_write_data <= g;
               rgb_loc <= rgb_loc + 18'd1;
               SRAM_address <= SRAM_address + rgb_loc;
            end

          v_comp[5] = v_comp[4];
          v_comp[4] = v_comp[3];
          v_comp[3] = v_comp[2];
          v_comp[2] = v_comp[1];
          v_comp[1] = v_hold[7:0];


          state <= S_WRITE_B;
        end

        S_WRITE_B: begin
          if(lead_in == 1'b0) begin
                SRAM_write_data <= b;
            rgb_loc <= rgb_loc + 18'd1;
            SRAM_address <= SRAM_address + rgb_loc;
          end
          y <=y_hold;
          u_prime [15:8] <= u_comp[3];
          mult_1 <= 159*(u_comp[3]+u_comp[2]);
          mult_2 <= 52*(u_comp[4]+u_comp[1]);
          mult_3 <= 21*(u_comp[5]+u_comp[0]);
          u_prime [7:0] <= mult_1 - mult_2 + mult_3;


          if(lead_in==1'b1) begin
            lead in <=1'b0;
          end
           = u_v_toggle + 8'd1;
          if(u_v_toggle == 8'd2) begin //reset toggle after 2 cycles of the common case
            u_v_toggle = 8'd0;
          end
          state <= S_READ_Y;
        end



        default: state <= S_IDLE;
      endcase
    end


  end




  // 7 segment displays
  convert_hex_to_seven_segment unit7 (
    .hex_value(SRAM_read_data[15:12]),
    .converted_value(value_7_segment[7])
  );

  convert_hex_to_seven_segment unit6 (
    .hex_value(SRAM_read_data[11:8]),
    .converted_value(value_7_segment[6])
  );

  convert_hex_to_seven_segment unit5 (
    .hex_value(SRAM_read_data[7:4]),
    .converted_value(value_7_segment[5])
  );

  convert_hex_to_seven_segment unit4 (
    .hex_value(SRAM_read_data[3:0]),
    .converted_value(value_7_segment[4])
  );

  convert_hex_to_seven_segment unit3 (
    .hex_value({2'b00, SRAM_address[17:16]}),
    .converted_value(value_7_segment[3])
  );

  convert_hex_to_seven_segment unit2 (
    .hex_value(SRAM_address[15:12]),
    .converted_value(value_7_segment[2])
  );

  convert_hex_to_seven_segment unit1 (
    .hex_value(SRAM_address[11:8]),
    .converted_value(value_7_segment[1])
  );

  convert_hex_to_seven_segment unit0 (
    .hex_value(SRAM_address[7:4]),
    .converted_value(value_7_segment[0])
  );

  assign
    SEVEN_SEGMENT_N_O[0] = value_7_segment[0],
    SEVEN_SEGMENT_N_O[1] = value_7_segment[1],
    SEVEN_SEGMENT_N_O[2] = value_7_segment[2],
    SEVEN_SEGMENT_N_O[3] = value_7_segment[3],
    SEVEN_SEGMENT_N_O[4] = value_7_segment[4],
    SEVEN_SEGMENT_N_O[5] = value_7_segment[5],
    SEVEN_SEGMENT_N_O[6] = value_7_segment[6],
    SEVEN_SEGMENT_N_O[7] = value_7_segment[7];

  assign LED_GREEN_O = {resetn, VGA_enable, ~SRAM_we_n, Frame_error, top_state};

endmodule
```

The `define_state.h` file:

```
`ifndef DEFINE_STATE

// This defines the states
typedef enum logic [1:0] {
    S_IDLE,
    S_ENABLE_UART_RX,
    S_WAIT_UART_RX
} top_state_type;

typedef enum logic [4:0] {
    
    S_IDLE,
    S_LEAD_IN_1_U,
    S_LEAD_IN_2_U,
    S_LEAD_IN_3_V,
    S_LEAD_IN_4_V,
    S_LEAD_IN_Y,
    S_WRITE_R,
    S_WRITE_G,
    S_WRITE_B,
    S_READ_Y,
    S_READ_U,
    S_READ_V,
    
} state_type;

typedef enum logic [1:0] {
    S_RXC_IDLE,
    S_RXC_SYNC,
    S_RXC_ASSEMBLE_DATA,
    S_RXC_STOP_BIT
} RX_Controller_state_type;

typedef enum logic [2:0] {
    S_US_IDLE,
    S_US_STRIP_FILE_HEADER_1,
    S_US_STRIP_FILE_HEADER_2,
    S_US_START_FIRST_BYTE_RECEIVE,
    S_US_WRITE_FIRST_BYTE,
    S_US_START_SECOND_BYTE_RECEIVE,
    S_US_WRITE_SECOND_BYTE
} UART_SRAM_state_type;

typedef enum logic [3:0] {
    S_VS_WAIT_NEW_PIXEL_ROW,
    S_VS_NEW_PIXEL_ROW_DELAY_1,
    S_VS_NEW_PIXEL_ROW_DELAY_2,
    S_VS_NEW_PIXEL_ROW_DELAY_3,
    S_VS_NEW_PIXEL_ROW_DELAY_4,
    S_VS_NEW_PIXEL_ROW_DELAY_5,
    S_VS_FETCH_PIXEL_DATA_0,
    S_VS_FETCH_PIXEL_DATA_1,
    S_VS_FETCH_PIXEL_DATA_2,
    S_VS_FETCH_PIXEL_DATA_3
} VGA_SRAM_state_type;

`define DEFINE_STATE 1
`endif
```

All the states have been defined in an external file `define_state.h`. There shouldn't be any previous declarations of the state (I have checked this to the best of my ability.)  Thus, I am unsure as to why the error is persisting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two enum types that use the same value - `S_IDLE`. That is not allowed. enum types in the same scope are not allowed to share values. You either need to think of a different name or put the two type declarations in separate packages. These type definitions would be better off in a package, anyway, rather than using an include file as you have.

```
typedef enum logic [1:0] {
    S_IDLE,                           // here
    S_ENABLE_UART_RX,
    S_WAIT_UART_RX
} top_state_type;

typedef enum logic [4:0] {
    S_IDLE,                            // and here 
    S_US_STRIP_FILE_HEADER_1,
    S_US_STRIP_FILE_HEADER_2,
    S_US_START_FIRST_BYTE_RECEIVE,
    S_US_WRITE_FIRST_BYTE,
    S_US_START_SECOND_BYTE_RECEIVE,
    S_US_WRITE_SECOND_BYTE
} UART_SRAM_state_type;
```

Comment: I have fixed that, but it still returns the same error.

Comment: @UdaySharma I fixed at and got very many, very fundamental errors (you are trying to assign to a variable from more than one place).